# Python encryption with a master key

Tags: python, encryption

I need to put sensitive data in a database that can be seen by everyone in our organisation
I wish to encrypt the data and then put it in a text field
The data will be accessible via a GUI that will ask the user to enter a password that will be used to encrypt/decrypt the data
I don't trust the users to remember their passwords so I want to have a single master key that will decypt all data

The only way I can see to do this is to encrypt the data with a symmetric key and at the same time encrypt a copy of the password with a public key.  The private key can then be used to decrypt the symmetric key and thus decrypt the data if the user loses their key.

Is this a sensible way to do it or am I making it harder than I need to?

I will be doing this in Python.  Looking at other posts it seems that Pycrypto is the library I should be looking at.  Is this right?

Thanks

Comment: These kind of questions are better asked at our [IT security sibling site](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this method would result in a complicated design which will be more complicate to scale and maintain.

Better approach would be to use symmetric key for storing and retrieving the sensitive data form the database. The user can be prompted for their key and the data can be decrypted or encrypted. This [link](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/) will help you implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should never encrypt a password if it is not strictly required by the protocol.

What you could do instead:

1. create a random symmetric key for each field
2. encrypt that key with a master public key (for which the master private key is kept safe, e.g. [on a stick](http://jeffdunham.wikia.com/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Jalapeno_on_a_Stick))
3. encrypt that same key with a symmetric user key retrieved from performing PBKDF2 over the password
4. encrypt the data with the symmetric key
5. store the symmetric key "wrapped" with the master public key and user key, the salt required for the PBKDF2 function (prefixed by some kind of version indicator of the protocol if possible) and the ciphertext together

Now you just have to put in place a procedure on how to act when the user forgets his password. It would require setting up a new password and retrieving the data.